# Avoiding parsing errors due to space character as delimiter + text in Python text files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text-files, delimiter

If a textfile contains a character, say space, as both a delimiter and part of text, how should we read the file using pandas read_csv, read_table or file read?

Comment: There is no reasonable way to help you without an example of the text you are intending to parse.

Comment: You also shouldn't be using space delimited files, thats very confusing, can you change the format of the text file? There's no possible way to know if a file containing "the black cat ball" is supposed to break up as ["the", "black", "cat", "ball"] or ["the", "black cat ball"], or any other variation

Comment: @rahlf23 For example, I have 8 fields separated by space, but in few rows i get "05440 1988 2018 439 49.0116 10.9308 Weißenburg Emetzheim Bayern" Here, "Weißenburg Emetzheim" belongs to a single field.

Comment: @RichardStoeffel Yes, all the text files in the dataset are space delimited. As there are many of such files from the source im using, is there a quick way to change them to comma-separated files?

Comment: Besides manually there's no quick way, is the format 7 numbers and then a name 100% of the time?

Comment: @RichardStoeffel is correct, you shouldn't be using space delimited files for the reasons he mentioned. With that being said, is it always numbers followed by a name? If so, you can use `regex`

Comment: Yes, for a number of files, it is 6 numbers followed by two names.

Comment: Wait, so for your example the following: `Weißenburg Emetzheim Bayern` should be split into `Weißenburg Emetzheim` and `Bayern`? If so, then there is no reliable way of doing this...unless it is **always** a name of two words followed by a name of one word (or vice versa)

Comment: @rahlf23 it can be either, so there'd be a space in the first name or the second.

Comment: @AtiqaZafar Definitely first choice is to change the delimeter. If that is not possible, and you know for a fact the file will always be either 8 numbers, or 7 numbers and a name, you can use the answer I posted below to handle the last field

Comment: I see that Weißenburg and Emetzheim are both in Bayern in that example. Would it be possible to show us all, or most, of the possibilities in the files with which the software would have to cope?

Comment: @BillBell the first text field, say A, is a station name and the second,B, is the location of that station. A will always be in B. `Donaueschingen (Landeplatz), Baden Württemberg`,                                                                                 
`Arkona, Mecklenburg Vorpommern`,                                                                            
`Arolsen Volkhardinghausen, Hessen`

Comment: If you had commas separating these like in your comment, this is a very straightforward solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these array keys to gather elements dynamically, so the first 6 elements will be captured as you expect (Note that the `line` variable should be in some loop that iterates over every line in the file, assigning the line the to a variable named 'line'):

```
 elements = line.split(" ")
 int_fields = elements[:6]
 last_field = elements[6:]
```

The last field will either be your last integer, if its a single integer. If it is a string, like the name you posted in your exapmple, last_field will be an array. You can then join them into a single variable by treating it as a string (which the other integers will be when you split that string):

```
field = ""
for item in last_field:
    field += "{} ".format(item)
field.strip()
```

That will add all the words into one string, including spaces. The strip function removes extra spaces at the end.

Again though, using space delimited files is usually not a great approach, if you have access to whatever creates the files, change the delimiter to a comma or a pipe (|)

Answer (score 0):

This code might show you the basic idea.

- I used your sample line plus one line without the place data.
- Read the data line by line, splitting on white space.
- If only the numeric data is present put it out to temporary storage, in this code, `StringIO`. If there's string data too then format appropriately first.
- 'Rewind' the temporary storage and read it with pandas.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

for_pd = StringIO()
with open('zafar.txt') as zafar:
    for line in zafar:
        line = line.strip()
        items = line.split()
        if len(items) == 6:
            print(','.join(items), file=for_pd)
        elif len(items) == 9:
            print(','.join(items[:6])+',"{} ({}), {}"'.format(items[7],items[6],items[8]), file=for_pd)

for_pd.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(for_pd, header=None, names=['1','2','3','4','5','6','place'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      1     2     3    4        5        6                           place
0  5440  1988  2018  439  49.0116  10.9308                             NaN
1  5440  1988  2018  439  49.0116  10.9308  Emetzheim (Weißenburg), Bayern
```